# How to use mat-select with reactive forms formarray angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

So far, I've written below code

```html
<form [formGroup]="testForm">
    <div formArrayName="selects">
        <mat-form-field *ngFor="let select of selects.controls; let i = index">
            <mat-select [formControlName]="i">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of select.value.options" [value]="option">{{ option }}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</form>
```

**In the component file**

```js
testForm: FormGroup;

get selects() {
  return this.testForm.get('selects') as FormArray;
}

data = [{
  initial: 'one',
  options: ['two', 'three', 'four']
}, {
  initial: 'a',
  options: ['b', 'c', 'd']
}];

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    selects: this.formBuilder.array([]),
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
    this.selects.push(new FormControl(this.data[i]));
  }
}
```

But this is not working so far. What I am doing wrong here?

Find the [Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-components-demo-ymqhcf).

**Issue:** As you can see in the stackblitz, it is not showing the initial value and if we select the option, then also it is not working and also options are disappearing from the select if we select any option.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Hi @yurzui as you can see in the stackblitz, it is not showing the initial value and if we select the option, then also it is not working and also options are disappearing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example looks strange:

```
{
  initial: 'one', <------------  it is not in options array
  options: ['two', 'three', 'four']
}
```

But anyway if you want to make it work with FormArray then you should be mapping `initial` value and not the whole object:

```
this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  selects: this.formBuilder.array(this.data.map(item => new FormControl(item.initial))),
});
```

And your html should look like:

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let select of data; let i = index">
    <mat-select [formControlName]="i">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of select.options" [value]="option">{{ option }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

As you can see I loop over original `data` array.

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-components-demo-tgznxu?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Yeah, that's true, I missed it :-). I am trying your solution in my original code. I have one doubt, instead of using `data` to loop, can't we use `selects.controls`

Comment: We can use `selects.controls` but we need to get `options` somehow. We don't keep options in `FormArray`. Now it's only array of FormControl's. I use loop over `data` because I have `select.options` access